# I need a way to pass braces in a function

Tags: c++

As you can see this is a test program i have to use for a class assignment. My queastion is how do i pass braces in a set function (setName see below) . I dont see to have found the answer anywhere. cpp .
The programm below doesnt work because I cant pass braces of strings into the function setName. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Player{
    string name;
    int level;
    Player(string  x,int y){
        name=x; level=y;
        cout<<"Name of the player is:"<<name<<"and his level is:"<<level<<endl;
    }
    int getLevel(){
        return level;
    }
    string getName(){
    return name;
    }
    int setLevel(int m){
    level=m;
    }
    string setName(string k){
    name=k;
    }
};
class Party{
    string boss;
    std::vector<std::string> players;
    std::vector<int> players_level;
public:
    string party_name;
    Party(string u, string w){
    party_name=u;
    boss=w;
    }
    string getNames(int i){
    return players[i];
    }
    int getLevels(int i){
    return players_level[i];
    }
    void setNames(string l){
    players.insert(players.end(),l);
    }
    int setLevels(int n, int i){
    players_level[i]=n;
    }
    void add_new_player(string o){
    players.push_back(o);
    }
};
int main (){
Party party1("dragons","calisi");
party1.setNames({"Book1","Book2"});
cout<<party1.getNames(0);
}
```

Comment: `setNames` needs to take something like `std::initializer_list<std::string>`, `std::vector<std::string>`, etc. instead of just a single `string`.  And of course the implementation will have to be updated to insert all of those things into `players`.

Comment: comment above me, but "in addition", not "instead" of just a single string.

Comment: You can only pass a parameter to a function that matches the type the function expects. `setNames` requires a `std::string`. `{"book0", "book1"}` is not a string. Either call `setNames` twice: `setNames("book0"); setNames("book1");` or turn `setNames` into a function that takes a vector of strings (`std::vector<std::string>` )  or something like it.

Answer (score 1):

The `std::initializer_list` will help you. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) for the documentation. So, we need to add a new function to your Party class:

```
void setNames(std::initializer_list<std::string>il) {
    players.insert(players.end(), il);
}
```

We will override the existing function with this function. And the compiler takes care that the correct function will be called.

You need to include `#include <initializer_list>`. That's all. With that you will get the desired functionality.

Comment: +1. But I personally think you may tell OP that this is a part of C++11. Because there's no C++11 tag in the OP's problem.